# How can I convert animated gif to animated webp?

Tags: imagemagick, gif

On ubunt, I can convert animated .gif files to .webp format using imagemagick's `convert 1.gif 1.webp`, but then the animation is lost in the destination .web.

I'm wondering how to preserver the animation while transfoming the format?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ImageMagick doesn't have the ability to convert **animated** GIF to WebP. For this you should consider Google's **gif2webp**.

Google support page for gif2webp: https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/gif2webp

A quick search shows that gif2webp is part of the "webp" package for Ubuntu and has .deb packages available here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=webp under section "Exact hits"

To install on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install webp
```

Basic command line usage:

```
gif2webp input.gif -o output.webp
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I saw that but don't know how to install it on Ubuntu?

Comment: See my addition

Comment: Great, please also add how to install it: `apt install webp` and use it: `gif2webp 1.gif -o 1.webp

Comment: Would love it if someone made a GUI for this, heck, even if it's just `zenity` and made a PPA for it

Comment: Lol command line and a script is just s convenient ;)

Comment: On arch you need to run `pacman -S libwebp` to install this

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use **ffmpeg** because with a **single command** you can convert:

- gif animations with transparency preserved
- static images like .png, .jpeg
- videos
- optionally resize with dimensions ratio preserved

to webp.

This is the command:

```
ffmpeg -i ./inputfile -vf "scale=180:-1" -vcodec webp -loop 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p ./output.webp
```